# .net system tray application to launch when a USB device is plugged in

Tags: .net, usb, system-tray

How do I get my .net system tray application to popup when a USB device is plugged in?

Comment: What part do you need help with?  Popping-Up? or Detecting that a USB device is plugged in?

Comment: detecting a usb is plugged in (a specific usb device) and then having my .net app react to it (pop-up)

Answer (score 4):

You might look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DriveDetector.aspx) for an example app that does something like what you want.